# Is there a way that I can scroll contents of a div by taking my mouse over an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div that has a lot of elements that cross the length of the div so I was wanted to put an image an an arrow next to the div such that when I move my mouse over the image the content of the div gets scrolled

```
<div id="image"> go down  </div>
<div id="container">
    <div><a name=""></a> One </div>
    <div><a name=""></a> two </div>
    <div><a name=""></a> three </div>
    <div><a name=""></a> four </div>
    <div><a name=""></a> five </div>
    <div><a name=""></a> Six </div>
    <div><a name=""></a> Seven </div>
    <div><a name=""></a> eight </div>
    <div><a name=""></a> nine </div>
    <div><a name=""></a> ten </div>
    <div><a name=""></a> eleven </div>
    <div><a name=""></a> twelve </div>    

</div>​
```

Comment: I have posted the answer but next time please include the javascript that you use as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this in your java script..

```
$('#image').hover(function(){
    $('#container').animate({ 
        scrollTop: $('#container')[0].scrollHeight 
    }, 1000);
});​
```

Comment: why `[0]` with `$('#container')`

Comment: Thank you this worked. I had to import jQuery library though which I might not use anywhere else.

Comment: glad it helped. you can go with the above answer as well if you dont want to import extra JS.  Cheers.

Comment: Where is the `#hover` element in the original question?

Comment: When I tried it on my computer I named it "hover" so I forgot to edit that. But I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 2):

You can try scrollTo method.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function scrollWindow()
  {
  window.scrollTo(100,500);// 
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onmouseover="scrollWindow()" value="Scroll">
<p>SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL</p>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p>SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL</p>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p>SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL SCROLL</p>

</body>
```

Or

You can use jquery

```
$('#hover').hover(function(){
    $('#container').animate({ 
        scrollTop: $('#container')[0].scrollHeight 
    }, 1000);
});​
```